# RaspBMC not Samba sharing

Tags: raspbmc, media-server

I have 2 Pis. One a headless webserver running Raspbian and the other running RaspBMC.
The Raspbian Pi happily shares out with Samba, but despite being able to see the RaspBMC Pi, I cannot get to the shares from my Ubuntu PC, Windows 7 PC and Raspbian Pi. smb.conf is the same on both Pis.

```
[global]  
   workgroup = NET  
   name resolve order = lmhosts wins bcast host  
   interfaces = lo, eth0  
   security = share  
   map to guest = bad user  
   guest account = nobody  
   usershare allow guests = yes  
   read only = yes  
   create mask = 0700  
   directory mask = 0700  

[Movies]  
    path = /home/pi/Movies  
        browseable = yes  
        read only = yes  
        guest ok = yes  
        force user = pi
```

Sometimes smbd doesn't start/restart...

```
pi@raspbmc:~/Test$ sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart  
[ ok ] Stopping Samba daemons: nmbd smbd.  
[ ok ] Starting Samba daemons: nmbd smbd.  
pi@raspbmc:~/Test$ ps -A | grep mb   
 2195 ?        00:00:00 nmbd  
pi@raspbmc:~/Test$ sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart  
[....] Stopping Samba daemons: nmbd smbdstart-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 2199: No such process  
. ok   
[ ok ] Starting Samba daemons: nmbd smbd.  
pi@raspbmc:~/Test$ ps -A | grep mb  
 2273 ?        00:00:00 nmbd  
 2277 ?        00:00:00 smbd  
 2301 ?        00:00:00 smbd  
pi@raspbmc:~/Test$
```

I've tried re-installing Samba and stopping XBMC to no avail.

My next move would be a total re-install..............

Comment: I've got the same problem, did you fix it in the meantime? My /var/log/samba/log.smbd states this: `rpc_server/svcctl/srv_svcctl_reg.c:609(svcctl_$ svcctl_init_winreg: Could not open SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services - WERR_B$
[2013/12/28 12:50:22.086027, 0] rpc_server/srv_pipe_register.c:222(rpc_srv_reg$ rpc_srv_register: Failed to call the svcctl init function!`